# How to pass a while loop variable from Php to a JavaScript function that runs in realtime

Tags: javascript, php

What I'm trying to create right is basically a notification when someone messages you. It's simple, when I'm in the chat webpage and a friend message me a notification will appear next to his name. My problem is as the title suggest, where I'm finding difficulty passing a while loop variable from Php to a JavaScript function.

Here's my Php code:

```
<?php
$query = $db->prepare("
    SELECT frst_user AS frst, scnd_user AS scnd 
    FROM frnd_rqst
    WHERE (frst_user=:fid OR scnd_user = :fid)#
        AND status=2
");
$query->bindParam(":fid", $getid);
$query->execute();
while($row = $query -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $numrow = $query -> rowCount();
    $frst = $row['frst'];
    $scnd = $row['scnd'];   
    $sec_quer = $db->prepare("
        SELECT fname, lname, stud_id 
        FROM stud_bas 
        WHERE stud_id!=:sid 
            AND (stud_id=:fid OR stud_id = :tid)
    ");
    $sec_quer->bindParam(":sid", $getid);
    $sec_quer->bindParam(":fid", $frst);
    $sec_quer->bindParam(":tid", $scnd);
    $sec_quer->execute();
    $result = $sec_quer->fetch();
    $fname = $result['fname'];
    $lname = $result['lname'];
    $frid = $result['stud_id'];
?>

    <ul>
        <li  class="friend-message" id="<?php echo $frid;?>" value="<?php echo $frid;?>">
            <a href="#" ><?php echo $fname." ".$lname;?></a>
        </li>
        <p id="fridfrid<?php echo $frid;?>"></p>
    </ul>
<?php
}
?>
```

Here's the JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function numberOfMessages() {
    var no_msg = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var frid = "<?php echo $frid;?>";
    no_msg.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (no_msg.readyState==4 && no_msg.status==200) {
      document.getElementById('fridfrid' + frid).innerHTML = no_msg.responseText;
      }
    }
    no_msg.open('GET','php/testing.php?frid=' + frid, true);
    no_msg.send();
  }
  setInterval(function(){numberOfMessages()},1000);
</script>
```

I've tried putting the function inside the while loop but only works for the last output. I've also tried where you get all the names of but that doesn't seem to work for me also. Any suggestion?

Comment: If you need real-time server-client interaction, then probably you will need to implement https://nodejs.org/en/ or similar engine instead of php. Or else your server might soon run out of resources.

Comment: you might also want to look up Web Sockets.

Comment: @KiranShakya I don't think that would solve any problems. As far as I understand, the while loop just stops when there are no messages left and the goal is to have new messages get displayed as soon as they are popping in. Look into [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) as Jhect mentioned.